# Compare values in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. When values in data1['col1'] match with values in data2['col1'], I want to apply a string change in data1['col2']. I don't have any error, but the change is not applying.

Sample of the input :

```
data1 = {"col1": ["001", "002", "004"], "col2" : ["SL", "SL", "SL"]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2  = {"col1": ["009", "004", "025"]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

print(df1)
print(df2)

col1 col2
0  001   SL
1  002   SL
2  004   SL

col1
0  009
1  004
2  025

for idx, val in df1["col1"].iteritems():
    for idx2, val2 in df2["col1"].iteritems():
        if val == val2:
            df1["col2"][idx] = "SL MATCH"
```

Output expected :

```
print(df1)

col1      col2
0  001        SL
1  002        SL
2  004  SL MATCH
```

Comment: please provide a sample input and the expected matching output for clarity. `iteritems` is likely **NOT** the way to go ;)

Comment: what do you means by name changed? is it hardcoded? or some modification from some column content in df1 or df2?, and yeah some input output example can help ppl to help you

Comment: Hi both, thanks ! I edited my request with a sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check values by another column:

```
df1.loc[df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1']), "col2"] = "SL MATCH"
print (df1)
  col1      col2
0  001        SL
1  002        SL
2  004  SL MATCH
```

Or:

```
df1["col2"] = np.where(df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1']), "SL MATCH", df1["col2"])
```